# Why wont my clone work. Java

Tags: java

I have a class of objects called item but the clone function won't work.

```
Item newItem = addedItem.clone();
```

please help :'(

added:

```
public abstract class Item extends GameObjectsCls implements Cloneable

Item newItem = (Item)addedItem.clone();
```

and added the public clone method but now am asked for try catch statement. is that ok? public `Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {`

Comment: what are you expecting to get?

Comment: “Won't work” is not very useful to find some help on this site. You should give more details!

Comment: Have you tried `Item newItem = (Item)addedItem.clone();`? Does `Item` implement `Cloneable`? That being offered, [`Cloneable` is broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `Item` class needs to implement the `Cloneable` interface or else `clone()` will throw an exception. This is explained in the [documentation for `Object#clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()).

Second, your class needs to implement a public version of `clone()`, because the `clone()` method of `Object` is `protected`.

Finally, you may need to cast the result to an `Item` for the assignment to work, depending on how you declare `clone()` in class `Item`.

EDIT (based on OP's edit): Your `clone()` method should look something like this:

```
public class Item implements Cloneable {
    ...
    public Item clone() {
        return (Item) super.clone();
    }
}
```

There's no need to declare that it throws `CloneNotSupportedException`, because it won't.

I would recommend, however, that you stop using `clone()` altogether and simply implement a copy constructor:

```
public class Item {
    public Item(Item other) {
        // copy over relevant fields
    }
    // ... other constructors
}
```

Then you can create your "clone" like this:

```
Item newItem = new Item(addedItem);
```